# Connected manifold without connected regular level set admits exactly two connected components

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a connected smooth manifold and $f \in C^\infty(M)$ such that $0$ is a regular value of $f$. Moreover, suppose that $f^{-1}(0)$ is connected. Is it true that $M \setminus f^{-1}(0)$ has exactly two connected components?

As $0$ is a regular value of $f$, we know that $f^{-1}(-\infty,0]$ and $f^{-1}[0,+\infty)$ are both regular domains, but I am not sure if my assumptions are sufficient.

Comment: The assumptions certainly aren't necessary (for example, take $M = \mathbb R$ and $f \colon x \mapsto x^2$), so I guess you just mean sufficient?

Comment: @LSpice Yes, indeed. Good example. Another one would be the torus with the height function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $M$ is connected and a manifold, it is path-connected. Thus, any two points $x,y \in M$ such that $f(x), f(y) > 0$ can be joined by a path $\gamma$. Suppose $\gamma$ does not lie entirely in $f^{-1}(0,\infty)$.

Then let $p = \text{inf}\{ t \in [0,1] : f(\gamma(t)) \leq 0\}$ and $q = \text{sup}\{ t \in [0,1] : f(\gamma(t)) \leq 0\}$. Then $p, q \in f^{-1}(0) = N$, and since $N$ is path-connected, we can join $p$ and $q$ by a path $\ell$ in $N$. As $f \circ \gamma$ takes positive values on $[0,p) \cup (q,1]$, first running through $\gamma_{[0,p]}$, then through $\ell$, and finally through $\gamma_{[q,1]}$ produces a path from $x$ to $y$ entirely contained in $f^{-1}[0,\infty)$. Using a tubular neighbourhood of $N$ in $M$, we can homotope this path so that it lies in $f^{-1}(0,\infty)$.

Thus, in any case, $x,y$ can be joined by a path in $f^{-1}(0,\infty)$, so this subset of $M$ is path-connected. The same is true for $f^{-1}(-\infty,0)$.

Comment: Why does using the tubular neighbourhood make it obvious that you can homotope into $f^{-1}(0, \infty)$?  Is it because $f^{-1}(0)$ disconnects the neighbourhood, and you know you can always homotope into a chosen one of the components of the complement?

Comment: @LSpice Sort of. In this case the tubular neighborhood will be diffeomorphic to $N\times \mathbb{R}$. In fact, since $0$ is a regular value, such a neighborhood will be given by the inverse image $f^{-1}(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Once you know that, you can think of the part of the path in $f^{-1}([0,\infty))$ as being a path in $N\times [0,\infty)$. Then using an isotopy of $\mathbb R$ supported on an appropriate compact set, you can push all of $N\times [0,\infty)$ diffeomorphically to, say, $N\times [a,\infty)$ for some $a>0$, keeping things far enough from $N$ fixed.

Comment: Now compose the path with the non-identity end of that isotopy to get the desired path.

Comment: I think in this case an easier homotoping argument can be given by simply using the flow of the normalised gradient vector field with respect to any Riemannian metric on $M$. No need to use tubular neighbourhoods.